# Graph: vary color/length vertextlabels based on frequency

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In this example I use a small network of 5 words.

```
words1 = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 12}, {{"word1", "word3"}, 
   11}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 10}, {{"word2", "word3"}, 
   5}, {{"word2", "word4"}, 5}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 5}}
```

> {{{word1,word2},12},{{word1,word3},11},{{word1,word4},10},{{word2,word3},5},{{word2,word4},5},{{word2,word5},5}}

```
edgeList = Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, words1[[All, 1]]]
```

> {"word1" -> "word2", "word1" -> "word3", "word1" -> "word4",   "word2"
>   -> "word3", "word2" -> "word4", "word2" -> "word5"}

To visualise this network I use this code:

```
edgeFun[pts_, e__] := 
  BezierCurve[{#, # - {-0.5, 0.5}, #2} & @@ pts[[{1, -1}]]];
pl = Graph[edgeList, DirectedEdges -> True, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle", EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeFun, 
  ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 80, Frame -> False]
```

The output is:

[image]

I would like to vary the color and fontsize based on the frequency of the different words.

```
words2 = {{"word1", 33}, {"word2", 27}, {"word3", 16}, {"word4", 
   15}, {"word5", 5}};
tally = Reverse@SortBy[words2, Last];
range = {Min@(Last /@ tally), Max@(Last /@ tally)}
words3 = First@# -> 
    Style[First@#, FontFamily -> "Cracked", FontWeight -> Bold, 
     FontColor -> 
      Hue[RandomReal[], RandomReal[{.5, 1}], RandomReal[{.5, 1}]], 
     FontSize -> Last@Rescale[#, range, {12, 70}]] & /@ tally
```

The desired output is:

[image]

In this example I can use 'VertexLabels' to define de different Characteristics. In my real problem I work with a large set of twitter-messages and thousends of different words. The solutions I thought was

```
words1 = words /. Rule -> List

pl = Graph[edgeList, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabels -> words2, 
  ImageSize -> 2000, ImagePadding -> 80, Frame -> False]
```

But this doesn't work

Who has a suggestion to do this on a smarter way?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the existing code? I agree that it is a bit cumbersome, but it seems to work. Is the problem that it's too slow?

Comment: You can do this by hand with 5 words. But if you want to create a graph with 5.000 words you I would like to use a smartert way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's generate some random words and graph

```
nWords = 15;
nEdges = 30;
words = RandomSample[DictionaryLookup[___], nWords];
wordsWeight = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, nWords];
edgeList = 
  Flatten[Table[
    UndirectedEdge[words[[i]], words[[j]]], {i, nWords}, {j, nWords}],
    1];
edgeList = RandomSample[edgeList, nEdges];
edgeWeight = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, nEdges];
```

If you want to scale each word and edge by their weight you can use, for example,

```
vls = Table[
   words[[i]] -> 
    Rescale[wordsWeight[[i]], {Min[wordsWeight], 
      Max[wordsWeight]}, {10, 20}], 
    {i, nWords}];
es = Table[
   edgeList[[i]] -> Thickness[
     Rescale[edgeWeight[[i]], {Min[edgeWeight], 
       Max[edgeWeight]}, {0.001, 0.01}]],
   {i, nWords}];¸
```

Then, feed these to `VertexLabelStyle` and `EdgeStyle`, e.g.

```
Graph[edgeList, DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle",  ImageSize -> 500, ImagePadding -> 80, Frame -> False,
 EdgeStyle -> es, VertexLabelStyle -> vls
 ]
```

Here's what I get

[image]

You can add more stuff to `vls` and `es` to tweak colors, fonts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your edge functions:

```
edgeFun[pts_, e__] := 
  BezierCurve[{#, # - {-0.5, 0.5}, #2} & @@ pts[[{1, -1}]]];
```

function to define edge styles:

```
estyle[edges_, weight_, color_, thickrange_] :=
 Block[{},
  Thread[edges -> (Directive[
        ColorData[color][Rescale[#, thickrange, {0, 1}]], 
        Thickness[#]] & /@ 
      Rescale[weight, {Min[weight], Max[weight]}, thickrange])]
  ]
```

function to define vertex label styles:

```
vlabelstyle[vert_, weight_, color_, vsizerange_] := Block[{},
  Thread[vert -> (Directive[
        ColorData[color][Rescale[#, vsizerange, {0, 1}]], 
        FontFamily -> "Cracked", #] & /@ 
      Rescale[weight, {Min[weight], Max[weight]}, vsizerange])]
  ]
```

main function to draw graph:

```
Options[WordGraph] = 
  Join[{"VertexColor" -> "DarkRainbow", "EdgeColor" -> "DarkRainbow", 
    "EdgeThickRange" -> {0.01, 0.05}, "VertexSizeRange" -> {12, 70}}, 
   Options[Graph]];

WordGraph[words_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=

 Block[{edges, eweights, vert, vweights, vcolor, ecolor, etrange, 
   vsrange, gopt},
  {vcolor, ecolor, etrange, vsrange} = {OptionValue["VertexColor"], 
    OptionValue["EdgeColor"], OptionValue["EdgeThickRange"], 
    OptionValue["VertexSizeRange"]};
  gopt = FilterRules[Flatten[{opts}], Options[Graph]];
  {edges, eweights} = Transpose[{DirectedEdge @@ #, #2} & @@@ words];
  {vert, vweights} = 
   Transpose[{#[[1, 1]], Total[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ 
     GatherBy[Flatten[Thread /@ words, 1], First]];
  Graph[vert, edges, gopt, EdgeShapeFunction -> edgeFun, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexLabelStyle -> vlabelstyle[vert, vweights, vcolor, vsrange], 
   EdgeStyle -> estyle[edges, eweights, ecolor, etrange], 
   GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"]
  ]
```

example 1:

```
words = {{{"word1", "word2"}, 12}, {{"word1", "word3"}, 
    11}, {{"word1", "word4"}, 10}, {{"word2", "word3"}, 
    5}, {{"word2", "word4"}, 5}, {{"word2", "word5"}, 5}};
WordGraph[words, ImagePadding -> {{10, 100}, {10, 100}}]
```

[image]

example 2:

```
l = 40; e = 60; words = 
 Transpose[{RandomChoice[
    RandomSample[DictionaryLookup[___], l], {e, 2}], 
   RandomInteger[{1, 20}, e]}];

WordGraph[words, "VertexColor" -> "AvocadoColors", 
 "EdgeColor" -> "SouthwestColors", "VertexSizeRange" -> {5, 30}, 
 "EdgeThickRange" -> {0.001, 0.015}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{10, 40}, {10, 40}}]
```

[image]